# Is there a way to cure zombie infection?

Tags: organ-trail

One of my guys got bitten by a zombie. Medkits say that they are unable to cure infections though. Is there any way to cure a zombie bite, or do I just have to put him down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cure for an infection, but they'll only turn if they are incapacitated.

When an infected gets incapacitated, do everything you can to get his health up again (stop the car, give him a medkit, rest). If you are fast enough, he won't turn (but he still is infected).

Source: [Steamcommunity](http://steamcommunity.com/app/233740/discussions/0/846957263099441321/)